# in windows batch file, how to loop 2 sets simultaneously

Tags: batch-file

In windows batch file, if I have two sets, how do I loop them simultaneously(not nested loop)?

> SET A=(1,2,3) SET B=(A,B,C)

loop `(1,A), (2,B), (3,C)` pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "A=1,2,3"
set "B=A,B,C"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set f1=0
set f2=0
for %%Z in (%A%) do (
   set /a f1=f1+1
   for %%Y in (%B%) do (
      set /a f2=f2+1
      if  !f1! == !f2! (
         echo [%%Z,%%Y]        
      )
   )
   set f2=0  
)
```

Cannot be done without some nesting. I preferred rectangular brackets to avoid escaping with the normal ones.

Comment: @aschipfl - 0_o. I'm an idiot. Fixed. Will try to find more optimal solution with only one temp variable.

Comment: No, you are for sure not an idiot, just nobody is perfect... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This method may be used with any number of simultaneous sets.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "A=1,2,3"
set "B=A,B,C"

rem Separate A set into individual array elements
set i=0
for %%a in (%A%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "A[!i!]=%%a"
)

rem Separate B set into individual array elements
set j=0
for %%b in (%B%) do (
   set /A j+=1
   set "B[!j!]=%%b"
)

if %i% neq %j% (
   echo A and B have not the same number of elements
   goto :EOF
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo (!A[%%i]!,!B[%%i]!)
```

You may read further details on array management in Batch files at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

---

Another, perhaps simpler method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "A=1,2,3"
set "B=A,B,C"

(for %%a in (%A%) do echo %%a) > A.txt
< A.txt (
   for %%b in (%B%) do (
      set /P "A="
      echo [!A!,%%b]
   )
)
```