# Copy and Rename files using two txt files

Tags: batch-file, copy

I am not really familiar with batch scripts so I would really appreciate some help here!
I have been trying to copy and rename a bunch of files using two txt files.
The chart_list.txt file will have the origin names.

```
chart_list.txt
Chart_A1_86_88.png
Chart_A2_86_88.png
Chart_B1_86_88.png
Chart_B2_86_88.png
```

The newchart_list.txt file will have the destination names.

```
newchart_list.txt
Chart_A1.png
Chart_A2.png
Chart_B1.png
Chart_B2.png
```

Looking at the following post ([in windows batch file, how to loop 2 sets simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326956/in-windows-batch-file-how-to-loop-2-sets-simultaneously) and [Copy a list (txt) of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257948/copy-a-list-txt-of-files)), I came up with the following :

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set src_folder=C:\Source
set dst_folder=C:\Destination
set flag=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (chart_list.txt) DO (
set /A flag+=1
echo !flag!
set flag2=0
    for /f "tokens=*" %%j in (newchart_list.txt) DO (
        set /A flag2+=1
        echo !flag2!
        if !flag! == !flag2! (
        copy "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%\%%j" /Y
        )
    )
)
@pause
```

The purpose is really to have the name in the first line of chart_list and newchart_list to match.
However, when I execute the command nothing happens. 
the cmd window shows

```
1
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
0
```

(I added the `echo` command to see if flag and flag2 were actually changing but it doesn't seem to be the case for flag2 which remains set to 0).

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: eg. `set flag = 0` Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG[Space]" to a value of "[Space]N" `Flag[space]` is NOT the same as `Flag`

Comment: @Magoo Thanks a lot! I edited the post based on your comments but cannot get flag2 to "deviate" from 0...

Comment: There's a typo: `set A/ flag2+=1` should read `set /A flag2+=1` (note the position of the `/`)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can two text files be read in parallel by a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214874/how-can-two-text-files-be-read-in-parallel-by-a-batch-file) or [Combining multiple text files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521799/combining-multiple-text-files-into-one)

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the links and the typo. Question has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "fileOld=chart_list.txt"
Set "fileNew=newchart_list.txt"
Set "dirSrce=C:\Source"
Set "dirDest=C:\Destination"

(For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%A In ("%fileOld%") Do (Set /P "B="<&3
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo(Copy /Y "%dirSrce%\%%A" "%dirDest%\!B!"
        EndLocal)) 3<"%fileNew%"
Pause
```

Just fill in the variables on lines `3`-`6` with your specific data, *(do not add trailing backslahes to directory paths and do not include doublequotes or remove those which currently exist)*.

If you are happy with the output, you can remove `Echo(` from line `10` and delete the last line, to actually perform the `Copy` procedure.

*The script does not check whether those variables are valid, exist, have matching number of lines etc. I'll leave that to you to work out as necessary*.

**Edit**

Here's an alternative method more along the lines of your original, *(but using the `Find` command)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "src_folder=C:\Source"
Set "dst_folder=C:\Destination"
Set "flag=0"
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%A In ("chart_list.txt") Do (
    Set /A flag+=1
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=]" %%B In ('
        "Find /N /V ""<"newchart_list.txt"|Find "[!flag!]""'
    ) Do Copy /Y "%src_folder%\%%A" "%dst_folder%\%%C")
```

…and without the flag or need for delayed expansion, *(same method as Aacini's but using `Find` instead of `FindStr`)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "src_folder=C:\Source"
Set "dst_folder=C:\Destination"
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=[]" %%A In ('Find /N /V ""^<"chart_list.txt"') Do (
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=[]" %%C In ('Find /N /V ""^<"newchart_list.txt"'
    ) Do If "%%C"=="%%A" Copy /Y "%src_folder%\%%B" "%dst_folder%\%%D")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler, but not very efficient:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set src_folder=C:\Source
set dst_folder=C:\Destination

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N "^" chart_list.txt') DO (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%x in ('findstr /N "^" newchart_list.txt') DO (
        if %%i == %%x (
            copy "%src_folder%\%%j" "%dst_folder%\%%y" /Y
        )
    )
)
pause
```

If the files to process are large, it is better to use anyone of the other methods suggested elsewehere. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214874/how-can-two-text-files-be-read-in-parallel-by-a-batch-file#comment63856885_38214875)